# database value not updated in hibernate using @Embeddable vlue type object

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello  i am new in hibernate and try simple example code.

here i am using Hibernate and save a user object into database.

Model Entity:- userinfo which have Address class object as member variable.

UserInfo.java

```
package org.hibernate.dto;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="User_Info")
public class UserInfo 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userid;
    @Column(name="UserName")
    private String username;

    @Embedded
    private Address ad;

    public Address getAd() {
        return ad;
    }
    public void setAd(Address ad) {
        this.ad = ad;
    }
    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Address.java

```
package org.hibernate.dto;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address 
{

private String city;
private String state;


public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

}
```

HibernateTest.java

```
package org.hibernate.Test;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.dto.*;
import HibernateUtils.*;


public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         UserInfo user=new UserInfo();

        user.setUsername("Yogendra");

         Address a1=new Address();

         a1.setCity("pune");

        Session session = HibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(user);

        tx.commit();

    }

}
```

The main problem is their only username and userid is updated in database no entry for address fields.

please point out if i made some mistake.

Comment: Why should it. The address isn't set on the user object so hibernate doesn't know anything about it. You are only constructing an address and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the address to user anywhere. Add `user.setAd(a1)` and it will work.